# Error handling when defining dtype while loading a dataset with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Loading a data set and defining data type like this

```
columns2type = { column1: str, 
                 column2: int,
                 ...
               }

df = pd.read_csv("path/file",dtype = column2type)
```

How can I hand errors like

```
pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce')
```

Is it possible to do this directly?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by *"do this directly"*?

Comment: Directly mean, defining data type using my dictionary and handily error at that same time. For example if I define column2 as int but there is a value like this "No", this is going to give me an error. This can be avoided with  errors='coerce'. So, can I hand error while reading the csv and not after being read??

Answer (score 1):

Unlike pd.to_numeric, pd.read_csv does not accept a parameter such as `errors='coerce'`, but, as per [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), `converters` parameter accepts *"Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns"*.

So, given the following *file.csv*:

```
column1,column2
1,7
2,8
3,9
A,10
5,11
6.78,12
```

You can import it like this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    "file.csv",
    sep=",",
    converters={
        "column1": lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors="coerce")
    },
)

print(df)
# Output
   column1  column2
0     1.00        7
1     2.00        8
2     3.00        9
3      NaN       10
4     5.00       11
5     6.78       12
```

Comment: I havent tried yet but sounds like a good idea. Thanks!